# How do I implement automatic data paging in Titanium when the user scrolls to the bottom row of a table view?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I'm working on a Titanium project that has hundreds of records users can scroll through (think music albums/songs), in different categories.

Does anyone have an idea as to how I could possibly use a scrolling table view that fetches the next set of data when the user scrolls to the bottom? I know how to do this on a web page using jQuery, but not sure how I would implement it with the table view?

Depending on the size of data fetched, I may cache it in a local database, but not sure what sort of size limits I'll hit. I just don't want to have to have a very large app that needs to be downloaded initially by the users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've found a sample that should be a great starting point:

https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/table_view_dynamic_scroll.js

From this, I will periodically make paging calls to my web service.

[EDIT] - Looks like the KitchenSink demo was just updated yesterday! New link: https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/ui/handheld/ios/baseui/table_view_dynamic_scroll.js
Based on this new link, does anyone know if this only works in iOS?

Comment: Turns out that this method is not compatible with android due to lack of Y offset information in the scroll listener of the tableview control. I'll just have this method in an iPhone-specific view, and an Android-specific view that uses more traditional paging like so: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/140662/table-view-with-page-selection